# Submitting application which supports only 64-bit devices to AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, arm64

Is it OK if application supports only arm64 architecture (iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus)? I have specified only arm64 in the Build Settings in the fields "Architectures" & "Valid Architectures" and also in the Info section in the field "Required device capabilities". Does not this lead to the rejection of application when submitting it to AppStore?

Comment: What is the reason for supporting 64-bit only?

Comment: In my particular case it is a little bit of workaround - application is using HealthKit and M7 motion chip (which is available only on iPhones 5S, 6 and 6 Plus). It seems there is no another way to exclude iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 from the list of supported devices (formally they support HealthKit, but without M7 it loses its sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for now it is impossible to submit application only with arm64 architecture - we received two errors during the submitting:

[image]

Thus it is necessary to include armv7 always.

Answer (score 0):

year,apple store statement：'all apps must adapt arm64 after 2015.02',so if you adapt only arm64 ,I think the apple store will not rejection it. recently，apple store review falstly,so you can try ...

Comment: Indeed it was easier to check this than to find an anwser :)